Python Selenium Proxy Bright Data Certificate Issue
I am trying to implement Bright Data proxy Residential IPs services into my Python Selenium code that is firing a webpage. Even when that page has a SSL certificate, it is loading in http not https.
I am getting certificate errors in my terminal.
My code:
# from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import os, sys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from seleniumwire import webdriver

delay = 30
custom_wait_time = 5

ua = UserAgent()
host = 'HOST'
port = 'PORT'

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

proxy_url = f'http://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}'


# set selenium-wire options to use the proxy
seleniumwire_options = {
    "proxy": {
        "http": proxy_url,
        "https": proxy_url
    },
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={ua.random}")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_url)
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# initialize the Chrome driver with service, selenium-wire options, and chrome options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
    options=options
)


webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True

# navigate to the target webpage
driver.get("https://example.com/")
time.sleep(delay)
# release the resources and close the browser
driver.quit()

Error:
[18496:26080:0710/154847.346:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1051)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for accounts.google.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[18496:26080:0710/154858.006:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1051)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[18496:26080:0710/154901.464:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1051)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.googletagmanager.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[18496:26080:0710/154905.509:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(1051)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.google-analytics.com failed:
----- Certificate i=1 (CN=Selenium Wire CA) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

And even when adding a custom certificate in chrome, the above errors stop but the location from which my site is hitting, user count is not increasing in google analytics
Also, my task manager shows multiple Chrome tasks/windows open even after my window closes, causing my system to hang after a few runs of this code.
